# AppleTV's Netflix browse menu is no longer accessible

Tags: appletv, netflix

I bought a new Apple TV from the local Apple Store yesterday. I set it up last night and all was working well. I activated **Netflix** and was quite pleased with how easy it was to browse TV shows and movies within Netflix. The next evening I started Netflix and the interface had completely changed. The only way to find anything new was to use the Netflix search interface. In other words, the browse interface was gone.

Using the same Netflix account I activated my Sharp TV's **Netflix app**. It has the browse interface. The same is true for my iPad and from the web on my MacBook Pro; i.e. the browse interface is there.

Lastly, I updated my Apple TV last night but I don't remember if I updated it before or after I used the Netflix brows interface.

When using Netflix from my Apple TV, how do I get to the Netflix browse interface?

I use an Apple TV (Gen 3), model MD199LL/A, running Apple TV Software 5.2.1(6025)
Sharp Aquos 60" HDTV

Comment: Well, this interface changed but after looking around I found what is good enough. By going to "Genres" and selecting a genre I am presented with the thumbnails of the offerings withing that genre. It's arguably more clumsy than other Netflix apps but at least its usable.

Comment: This is soo annoying and I get this all the time. What helps is to `reset` your ATV, and then it works again. But then you also have to setup the rest of your ATV again. I think it has something to do with the number of devices using Netflix.

Answer (score 1):

By 'browse interface' do you mean the view where you have a grid of cover art thumbnails?

After you log in to Netflix, you can go to "Suggestions for you" from the menu, and you'd be presented with the grid, customised to your favourite genres and recommendations based on what you've watched and liked. The TV Genres and Movie Genres are similar but each row is a different genre.

Comment: Yes, by "browse interface" I mean the view with a grid of cover thumbnails.

Comment: I understand the functionality of the app. but since I am new to Netflix the suggestions under "Suggested for You" are not what I care to see. 

The question is, is there is a way to get to the grid that lets you scroll through the genres? This is the interface I have on the iPad, the PS3, and my TV's Netflix interface. 

If there is no way to get to this interface then I will opt to use Netflix through other platforms, namely my TV's app and my iPad, as they fit my use habits much more closely then the Apple TV's Netflix app.

Thank you for your help. It is much appreciated.